# Web GUI for Python scripts

Tags: python, gui, web, computer-vision

I have several but independent computer vision pipelines which were original planned to run by a user via a cmd (task1 -> script_1.py, task2 -> script_2.py and so on).

All pipelines share some code (e.g. resize an image) but otherwise the entire procedure inside the pipeline is different, for instance some problems are solved with Deep learning others with classical image processing methods. All pipelines are running on an image analysis server with specific hardware.

Now the circumstances changed and I need a GUI for each pipeline. I have made bad experience with desktop applications and therefore this is no option for me, I want a GUI in a web browser, the user should open a site inside a browser and start the analysis.

Now my question is, is it possible to connect a web GUI with my existing python scripts which has to run on a image analysis server? Also I prefer a  Python solution, I am open to use other languages / tools if it makes things easier. I have two requirements, the framework should be established and robust and second the application and pipelines will continue  to grow in the future, so maintainability is important.

Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated,

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 0):

[here let me google that for you](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=python%20web%20library):
[Flask](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=flask),
[Tornado](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=python%20tornado),
[Django](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=django)

Any of the above frameworks should let you do what you want!